# How to update the state and schema in Cordapp?

Tags: corda

In corda dev mode,

For Example I have created a state with 3 Params, also with Schema for the state.

I have build the project and running it.

Due to the business need to need to 2 more params.

Below are the points I have understood from the corda docs.

1. Change the state.
2. Change the schema
3. Change the contract
4. Contract and state upgrade flow

I understood the existing states are updated with the new contract constraint.

Will the schema's gets updated by itself during the start of the node by giving {runMigrations=true}

Need help.

Comment: are you using corda enterprise? my answer will depend on your answer :)

Comment: No I'm using corda community version

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly runMigrations property is used only for Corda Enterprise and not for Corda Open Source.
   Take a look at the node configs available in enterprise and open source.

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.3/corda-configuration-file.html#database-properties-ref

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.3/corda-configuration-file.html

2. Performing state upgrades is handled differently in open source and enterprise.
   In Enterprise version, the tables are created as liquibase tables and liquibase is used to perform autotmatic database migration. 
   In Open source, liquibase is not used and tables are created as hibernate entities.
3. To do a state upgrade, you can add the three new params to your state, build the new jar, replace the old jar with the new one, and hibernate will take care of adding these new columns to the table. One more point on this is that even Hibernate advises not to use Hibernate to modify schema/data migration, so I would recommend you to create your own sql script and run it on the database. (This is done automatically by liquibase in the enterprise)
4. With corda 4 using signature constraints upgrade is easy, replace old jar with new jar(new jar has to be signed with the same signature used fro signing old jar), start the node. So you do not have to do the complex contract upgrade process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped